# Installing SQL Server 2012 on Windows 8

Tags: .net, sql-server, visual-studio-2012

I have installed Visual Studio 2012 Ultimate on windows 8 OS & now I want to install SQL Server Management Studio 2012.

According to my knowledge while installing VS 2012 SQL Server is also installed.

Now when i install SSMS, will it install SQL Server again ???

If yes, then is there any way to install SSMS only with out reinstalling SQL Server.

Comment: This question would be better suited for Server Fault. It's not about programming.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

While installing SQL Server there's an option to install "Client Tools" only. Use it and actual SQL Server DB engine will not be installed.